# Google Analytics - Grouping URL according to query paramters

Tags: regex, google-analytics, parameters, analytics

I am running a campaign and all partner traffic going through a landing page.
However, this page url is dynamic according to various parameters... so my GA reports show hundreds of lines.
I know I can filter the parameters out... but I would like to extract **the data per partner.**

Here is an example of the dynamic urls :

```
/landing-page/?ref=partner01&id=value1&email=value2&param=value3
```

I want to clean the urls but leaving the first parameter "**ref**" in the report.

I tried **ref=([^&]*)** but it is not working.

Then GA should group urls (I guess) and I can see a report with data sorted per partner.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Sorry... i' m trying with Regex... not a programming language because I want to work in GA.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want the urls to show up as: /landing-page/?ref=partner01

Comment: Exactly... so I can see GA stats per partner.

Comment: What about `*ref=*.+?(&=*)`? It should match everything before 'ref=' and then everything following until it hits '&='

Comment: This expression is not working in GA to filter urls.

Answer (score 1):

you may use 'Exclude URL Query Parameters' in a view settings and put there a list of all the unwanted parameters like `id,email,param`
Having `ref` out of the list will keep it in page path.
More on [Help pages](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en)

Comment: ok... by creating a new view and applying the parameters filter it works... but I cannot retrieve data prior to the setting date.

Comment: Past data in Analytics cannot be modified in any way

Comment: many other techniques mentioned work for incoming new data. to do a proper clean up of historic data you are still better off do it outside of GA as your options would be quite limited otherwise